# Long question titles cut off on badge page

Tags: bug, status-completed, css

On the "recently awarded" page for badges, questions with long titles are cut off, like so:

[image: Who asked this question?!]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build (after rev 2012.5.9.2511).